# How to pass --build-arg parameters from command line to docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arguments, parameter-passing

Suppose that I type the following command

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --build_args PARAM=1`

How should I write my docker-compose.yml such that the yml fiel gets the argument `PARAM`, whose value is `1`?

My yml file is below.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args: 
         - MY_PARAM: ${PARAM}
      ports:
         - "5000:5000"
    image: sample-img:1.0
```

I added

```
args: 
   - MY_PARAM: ${PARAM}
```

below `build`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can pass build arguments while using compose -

1. Allow arguments support in Dockerfile.

   ```
   FROM foo:bar   
   ARG PARAM
   ARG PARAM2
   .................
   ```
2. Now you can pass these arguments in two different ways -

   1. During runtime -

      ```
      docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --build-arg "PARAM=1 PARAM2=2"
      ```
   2. Within compose using shell  -

      ```
      $ export PARAM=1 PARAM2=2
      ```

      Change docker compose as below -

      ```
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.foo
      args:
        PARAM: ${PARAM}
        PARAM2: ${PARAM2}
      ```

      Build it -

      ```
      $ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
      ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! What I actually wanted was to access the value of the parameter in ```docker-compose.yml```. For example, given the code you wrote above, does this command work in ```docker-compose.yml``` ?
```image: my-iamge:${PARAM} ```

Comment: Yes, the 2nd solution "Within compose using shell" should work. If you export variables in shell, compose will be able to interpolate it.